# Monte Carlo Markov Chain Simulation Issues

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, monte-carlo

The Markov Chain is uniformly distributed across all $50$x$50$ matrices of entries $0$ and $$1 with no neighboring $1's$.  I am supposed to run a MC simulation to check the probability that the $25$x$25$ entry of this matrix is a $1$.

My method is to start with the zeroes matrix and run the chain by randomly selecting an entry to change.  If the new matrix is in the chain, a counter variable increases by one. If the $25$x$25$ entry is a $1$, another counter increases.  I was very careful with the chain.

I ran this method $2,000,000$ times and got that the probability was $.49$.  This seems a little high, and I'm worried that the chain doesn't touch anywhere near the $2$^$50$ entries.  Is this method OK?